# angularjs modal not displaying modal content from external html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

i have a modal in an external HTML file that i tried loading as my templateUrl in my App controller, but the template isn't displaying and not giving any error in my console

this is my controller file

```
app.controller('seCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$uibModal',   function($scope,$http,$uibModal,$log){

$scope.openmod = function (){
    console.log("modal clicked");
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
         //template: "<div ng-include src=\"'./assets/partials/sec-modals.html'\"></div>",
         templateUrl: './assets/partials/sec-modals.html',
          // windowTemplateUrl: './assets/partials/sec-modals.html',
        controller: 'secmodalCtrl', 
        resolve: {}
    });
};

}])
```

and this is my sec-modals.html

```
<div id="modal">
 <h1>welcome to the modal</h1>
</div>
```

notice i have tried using ng-include, windowsTemplateUrl but not also working
i would appreciate help

Comment: Sounds like it can't find the template. Are you certain the path is correct.

Comment: yes  i am very certain about it

Comment: Check your browser's *Network* console. There should be a request for that template. Make sure the resolved path is correct.

Comment: i can see the request on my browser's Network console and it is ok

Comment: Could just be the format of your template. It should have elements with classes "modal-header", "modal-body", etc. See the example code here ~ https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal